# How do I add the lat and long back into the response from Google's Timezone API?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Google's Timezone API to grab the timezone for specific lat and longs I pass to is. I am able to do this successfully but I want to add the corresponding lat and longs back into the data. How can this be done? Here is the code I am using:

```
#get timezone
result = []
google_key = '________________________'

for coord in range(0,len(latitude)):
    timezone = requests.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?timestamp=1331161200&location=' + str(latitude[coord]) + ',' + str(longitude[coord]) + '&key=' + google_key).json()
    result.append(timezone)

tz_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(result)
tz_df = tz_df['timeZoneName']
```

I'm looking to add the lat and long back to this dataframe so I can join it with another dataframe that has the same lat and longs. Hope this makes sense. Still early on in my programming career.

Comment: Are `latitude` and `longitude` python lists?Also, I'm not familiar with the Google API: what other columns besides `timeZoneName` are in `tz_df`?

Comment: latitude = list(ip_df['latitude'])
As for the tz_df there is only the one column right now. I'm trying to add the lat and long in their own columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `latitude` and `longitude` are python lists, pandas does the right thing when you try to turn them into new columns in your DataFrame:

```
tz_df['lat'] = latitude
tz_df['lon'] = longitude
```

Comment: I was thinking I could do that as long as the order of the output remains the same as the input. My only concern what that if at some point data ended up out of order then input and output might not match up correctly. I'm not sure under what conditions that would be a reality but I wanted to be prepared for it is it is possible. Does that make sense/

Comment: Gave this solution a try and it added the 'latitude' and 'longitude' as rows.

Comment: Not sure if my edit will be accepted but I found the issue. I had tz_df = tz_df['timeZoneName'] and it should have been tz_df = tz_df[['timeZoneName']]. Once this is fixed 'latitude' and 'longitude' gets added as columns.

Comment: edit your question or post an answer. But do not edit another user's answer.